# Android how can i Detect If OnResume Is Because Back Button on Because rel lunching the app

Tags: android

i'm trying to show an add on my app .

i want to show the add every time that the user launches the app or if the app is in the background  when the user relaunch it.

i added the function that shows the add in the onRestart() event and it seems to work fine.

my problem is that if the user goes back to a previous activity by pressing the android Back button it triggers the  onRestart() event as well.

is it possible to determine if the activity was loaded by the back button?

Thanks alot
Avi

Comment: I think you mean "ad", not "add".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, here is what you can do:

If you are starting an activity from another activity, instead of calling `startActivity()`, use `startActivityForResult()`. In the called `Activity`, override the `onBackPressed()`. Put some data in the returned intent and call `super.onBackPressed()`. In the caller activity you will then analyze this to know that back was pressed :)

Also, move the advertisement to the `onResume()` method which is called when the Avtivity becomes visible to the user.

Comment: @אVי I edited my answer to include your back button problem also

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to put your add in the Onresume() method of your main activity;)